# How to create splash screen for multiple flavours in flutter for both android and ios?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-productflavors

Is there any way for me to create different splash screen for multiple flavor in flutter?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by flavors? Are you referring to Android or iOS, which are platforms, or are you also meaning prod or dev versions of your app, which is what flavors are commonly used for? People are guessing, you need to give more info and actually respond to the answers posted... otherwise you are just wasting our time :-)

Comment: @GrahamD It's not really complicated topic and it means one thing afaik. https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors

Comment: I know what flavors are, I use them myself for dev and prod Firebase databases. It's just that the answers already provided are talking about platforms and you haven't disagred with them. So I thought I would check.

Answer (score 9):

I'll try to edit later for Android, but as for the iOS, here's the process.

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
```

That's how your LaunchScreen is defined in Info.plist.

Open XCode, add User-Defined Setting.

[image]

By opening the build settings and clicking the tiny + button.

[image]

Add a variable, like LAUNCH_SCREEN.

Now we will create another LaunchScreen, by creating new LaunchScreen, like called LaunchScreenFlavor2.

[image]

[image]

Once you create the new launch screen, and assign LAUNCH_SCREEN variable to that storyboards, scroll to the beginning of my answer, and give the variable in Info.plist. Like:

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>${LAUNCH_SCREEN}</string>
```

Comment: can you add for Android?

Comment: this package support flavor: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash @Eternity

Comment: @mirkancal Still, it requires this setup.

Comment: @bounxye then set up like whatever this is